# How to get the parameters from URL using python and streamlit

Tags: python, url, bootstrap-5, streamlit

I am creating a streamlit app where i need to get the parameters from the url as below.

```
Localhost:8501/id=profile
```

Where **id** is the id of an **html tag**
I am using the **bootstrap card** with tabs
Where each tab has it ID and once the user select the tab its id i passed to the URL.

So my question is how to get the ID of the tab in order to display the content inside each tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parameters with [st.experimental_get_query_params()](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/utilities/st.experimental_get_query_params):

From the documentation:

> Let's say the user's web browser is at
> http://localhost:8501/?show_map=True&selected=asia&selected=america.
> Then, you can get the query parameters using the following:

```
st.experimental_get_query_params()
{"show_map": ["True"], "selected": ["asia", "america"]}
```